# Evaluating Linear Regression Models

Tags: statistics, soft-question

I am running some linear regressions on my data.  The justification for using a linear regression is purely visual; when I plot the dependent against the independent variables, the relationship appears linear.  In any event, how do I determine that the model is a good fit?

Currently, I'm using $R^2$ to measure if the fit is "tight", and the $F$-statistics to see if the chosen variables are providing sufficient reduction in $RSS$.  Are these two statistics sufficient or what else can I use to evaluate the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean square error and mean absolute error are both good metrics to track as well since they tell you how good your model's predictions are.